# Use Python version v0 task fails in azure pipeline

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

```
- task: UsePythonVersion@0  
  inputs:  
    versionSpec: '3.x'  
    addToPath: true  
    architecture: 'x64'
```

**I get the following error on ubuntu18.04:**

```
##[error]Version spec 3.x for architecture x64 did not match any version in Agent.ToolsDirectory.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a known issue when using Python 3.6 on Ubuntu-latest (recently upgraded to default version 22.04): [Issue](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/544)

There are no tarballs for 22.04 for any python 3.6.* versions. Check this [link](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md) for pre-installed software for 22.04.

I am facing same error when using Python 3.6.x on Ubuntu-latest.

[image]

You could specify the image to Ubuntu-20.04 to use Python 3.6.x.

[image]

Or use Python 3.10.x on Ubuntu-latest image.

[image]

Comment: I am using ubuntu18.04, I have tried both version as mentioned by you, but still error is there.